# ROS Installations: Desktop, Server, Cloud

Tags: ros, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi yah all!  I am new to this wonderful world of ROS and setting up a small ROS lab to do some experimentation.  My question is this, does ROS Indigo Igloo only run on the desktop version of Ubuntu 14.04.1 or can it be set up on both the server installation and the cloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191679/ros-installations:-desktop,-server,-cloud/) by [Pingbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20118/pingbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pingbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20118/pingbot/) on 2014-09-02**:
Okay, I decided to get brave and install the full version of ROS on a LAMP server rather than on just a desktop. The install was rather easy and seems to have gone fine. Next, I'm going to throw together a personal cloud and see how that goes. Installed easily on Ubuntu desktop....liking this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Indigo can be installed on any of the various flavors of Ubuntu 14.04 - desktop, server, cloud, etc. (It can also be installed on many other flavors of linux with a little more work!).

The network transport in ROS isn't well-suited for internet-scale deployments, mostly because there are no security features, and there isn't a lot of tolerance to network failures like poor wifi. Most of the large deployments I've seen use ROS on the robot, and sometimes within a building, and then have a bridge to a different protocol over the internet. rosjs has been fairly popular here.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pingbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20118/pingbot/) on 2014-09-03**:
Thanks for the feedback.  Where can I download the latest version of rosjs?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-03**:
As with any ROS package, I start by looking at the package's wiki page. In this case, it looks like rosjs has been superseded by roslibjs, and they have installation instructions on their wiki page: http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs .